# How do I get the File API to look at my classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-io

I am reading an ascii file in in my eclipse project.

The default output folder is set as

```
my_proj/classes
```

It is on my source path and when I build it goes into my classes directory. All ok. However, when I try to get a handle to it in my code by doing

```
File myFile = new File("myFile.txt")
```

it won't work because that API looks at my project root. Not at my classes dir.

When I do:

```
System.out.println("Current path is = " + new File(".").getAbsolutePath ());
```

The project roo comes back not my classes dir.

So hence I can't get a handle to my File.

I would like to just have the File on the classpath and for the code to pick it up

Any tips?

Comment: You don't. You use `Class#getResource(String)`, where `String` is the path to your resource relative to the package of the class you are in. You can prefix that path with `/` to start at the root of the classpath instead of relative to the package of the class you're in.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Your_File")`

and then use something like

```
 File file=new File(url.toURI());
```

Edit: as pointed out by [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) and [jb-nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), if "Your_File" is not a file on the file system but is bundled within a jar, in that case you will have to work with the inputstream, `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Your_File")`

Comment: File API won't always work here. Use `url.getInputStream()`. I didn't -1.

Comment: The first part is right. The second part won't work as soon as the resource is in a jar (i.e. 99.9% of the times). Use `getResourceAsStream()` to get a readable stream.